# How to scale an svg image inserted using DrawingBrush

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to scale an svg image inserted using `DrawingBrush` as in the following code?

```
<Style x:Key="HamburgerMenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
    <Setter Property="Icon">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DrawingImage>
                <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M6 36v-3h36v3Zm0-10.5v-3h36v3ZM6 15v-3h36v3Z"
                                     Brush="Red"/>
                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
            </DrawingImage>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: why not scale the drawing image? Or wrap it all in a viewbox?

Comment: There is no DrawingBrush in the question.

Comment: @ Denis Schaf, there were errors when I tried to wrap it all in a viewbox. Can you please tell how can the drawing image be scaled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I think you should code as below:

```
<Style x:Key="HamburgerMenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
<Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
<Setter Property="Icon">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="auto" Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Image.Source>
                <DrawingImage>
                    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M6 36v-3h36v3Zm0-10.5v-3h36v3ZM6 15v-3h36v3Z" Brush="Red"/>
                    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                </DrawingImage>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

**Note:**
Since I didn't have the **Template** property, I removed it. If you have problems displaying the icon despite this property, you should check it.

Also, if you are not sensitive to the use of **Drawing Image**, you can use the **Path** tag

```
<Path Stretch="Fill" Height="30" Width="30" Data="M6 36v-3h36v3Zm0-10.5v-3h36v3ZM6 15v-3h36v3Z" Fill="Red"></Path>
```

Comment: @ KeyvanSFX, sorry that I didn't include the complete code snippet. I am using the `DrawingImage` within `<Setter.Value>`. I updated my question. When I inserted your code, the Icon disappeared. Can you please tell the necessary changes to be made?

Comment: Ok I will update the answer after checking your code.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. The image still doesn't appear. The code in the `Template` responsible for inserting the icon is `<Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{TemplateBinding Icon}"/>`. Should I make any changes to this? You can find the complete `MenuItemControlTemplate1` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74769483/12526953)

Comment: Is the Icon not appearing because there is `Image` in both the `Style` as well as the `Template`?

Comment: Yes, the possibility of interference is very high because both have the same effect on the UI, that's why nothing is displayed.